# What does it mean for the tensor functor to be right exact?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, exact-sequence

If I am applying the right exact functor $- \otimes M $ to the short exact sequence $$0 \to \mathfrak{a} \to A \to A / \mathfrak{a} \to 0 \,,$$ do we have to write the new sequence as $$\mathfrak{a} \otimes M \to A \otimes M \to (A / \mathfrak{a}) \otimes M \to 0 \,,$$ (without the zero on the left ) or we can still write it as $$0 \to  \mathfrak{a} \otimes M \to A \otimes M \to (A / \mathfrak{a}) \otimes M \to 0 \,,$$ (with the zero on the left)?

If the second case is the right, can anyone tell me what is exactly the meaning of tensor is a right exact functor?

Comment: (Code of conduct) Unfriendly, "You could Google this in 5 seconds." Friendly, “If you Google 'exact functors' or 'tensor is a right exact functor', you’ll find tutorials/articles/posts that can explain them".

Comment: I am so sorry for doing wrong things @Apass.Jack  but I know the definition of right exact that it preserves the right exactness of a right exact sequence but here I am asking about the zero on the left, how it affects it? I could not understand this from wikipedia

Comment: Do either of these posts answer your question? [What is a typical example of the tensor product of modules failing to be left exact?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/39380) or [Proving that the tensor product is right exact](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81640)

Comment: If $0 \to \mathfrak{a} \to A \to A/\mathfrak{a} \to 0$ is exact, then so is the sequence $\mathfrak{a} \to A \to A/\mathfrak{a} \to 0$. Since $- \otimes M$ is right exact (i.e., it preserves the right exactness of a right exact sequence), then $\mathfrak{a} \otimes M \to A \otimes M \to (A/\mathfrak{a}) \otimes M \to 0$ is exact.

Comment: @MathIgnorance You may want to pick up a textbook to learn. Wikipedia is more for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### The definition of right-exact-ness of $-\otimes_R M$

The meaning of  "$- \otimes M $ is a right exact functor" is, whenever
$$ 0\to B\to A\to C\to 0$$ is a short exact sequence (in the category of $R$-modules), the induced sequence
Assume a commutative ring $R$ and a $R$-module $M$.

$$ B\otimes_R M\to A\otimes_R M\to C\otimes_R M\to 0$$ is also a short exact sequence.

The description above is basically paraphrasing [the definition of right-exact-ness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_functor) word-for-word.

###### What about the left $0$?

The question is what happens to the $0$ at the left of the induced sequence. Or, what is the same, whether the induced map $B\otimes_R M\to A\otimes_R M$ is injective or not.

It depends.

- It can happen that that induced map is not injective. For example, consider the exact sequence
  $$0\to 2\Bbb Z\stackrel{i}\to\Bbb Z\stackrel p\to\Bbb Z/\Bbb 2Z\to0$$
  where $i$ is the inclusion map (and hence $p$ is the quotient map). After we apply $-\otimes_\Bbb Z\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$,
  the sequence becomes
  $$0
  \to2\Bbb Z\otimes_\Bbb Z\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\stackrel{i\otimes_\Bbb Z\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z}
  \to\Bbb Z\otimes_\Bbb Z\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\stackrel {p\otimes_\Bbb Z\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z}
  \to\Bbb Z/\Bbb 2Z\otimes_\Bbb Z\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z
  \to0$$
  The module $2\Bbb Z\otimes_\Bbb Z\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z\otimes_\Bbb Z\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z=\Bbb Z\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ since $2\Bbb Z$ is isomporhic to $\Bbb Z$. It is generated by $2\otimes_\Bbb Z\overline1\not=0$.
  $$(i\otimes_\Bbb Z\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)(2\otimes_\Bbb Z\overline1)
  =2\otimes_\Bbb Z\overline1
  =(2\cdot1)\otimes_\Bbb Z\overline1
  =1\otimes_\Bbb Z(2\cdot\overline1)
  =1\otimes_\Bbb Z 0=0,
  $$
  which shows the map $i\otimes_\Bbb Z\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ is not injective.
- It can happen that induced map is still injective.
  If that is true for any injective map $B\to A$, then $-\otimes_R M$ is an exact functor. We call $M$ a flat $R$-module.
  For example, every free $R$-module is also a flat $R$-module.

---

We can, of course, always write a sequence of any maps. What concerns us is whether we can call it an exact sequence.

Given a short exact sequence $$0 \to \mathfrak{a} \to A \to A / \mathfrak{a} \to 0 \,,$$ we can, in general, only write a "right-exact" short sequence,
$$\mathfrak{a} \otimes M \to A \otimes M \to (A / \mathfrak{a}) \otimes M \to 0.$$ Here "right-exact" means although the sequence is "short" and exact, there is no zero on the left.

Only with more conditions on $\mathfrak{a}, A, M$, etc., we may have a "full-exact" short sequence $$0 \to  \mathfrak{a} \otimes M \to A \otimes M \to (A / \mathfrak{a}) \otimes M \to 0 \,$$ with the zero on the left.

Comment: An exercise: Replace the $2$ in the example with $3$s or a variable for positive integer $>1$.